# UIDatePicker with single row

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

In my application i need to integrate UIDatePicker view with  single row (only one row needs to display, that's a selection row.  UIDatePicker selection functionality is same like scrolling date up and down. i dont want to change that. ). like this

[image]

is it possible in Native UIDatePicker? if yes give me some idea. if not suggest any custom Date picker(that should not give any problem while move to app store). Guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: why -1? may i know the reason?

Comment: Please give me the reason before giving down vote. Even its closed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by simply connecting to your designer for few images like

```
1. Background
2. Separator
```

All you have to do is create interface design like this and parse current date in required format with NSDateFormatter and put it as required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have update the questions . i dont want to change the picker functionality. Plz update ur answer.

Comment: UIDatePicker doesn't allow change of height so you have to create component yourself. I am looking around and if I find custom solution I will definitely post here.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Do That.**

`UIDatePicker` displays a `UIPickerView` and Unfortunately, size of `UIPickerView` cannot be changed.

**My answer :** Even If you found any Hack ,pleas don't use that code, As It will go against **Human Interface Guidelines** (by making Touch Targets too small).